# Is a non-correlated exists(...) query in the where clause executed for each row or just once?

Tags: sql, postgresql, correlated-subquery

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   t1, t2
WHERE  t1.some_id = t2.some_id
       and
       not exists(select true from some_table where some_column = true)
```

Here, the `not exists(select true from some_table where ...)` does not refer to `t1` or `t2` from the main query.

Is this `not exists(select true from some_table where ...)` executed **just once** or **for every tuple** from the product between `t1` and `t2` for which `t1.some_id = t2.some_id` is true?

In other words, if it is executed just once, an empty table can be returned immediately if the result is false. Logically, we have written:

```
if (not exists(select true from some_table where some_column = true))
    SELECT *
    FROM   t1, t2
    WHERE  t1.some_id = t2.some_id
else
    empty table
```

Comment: Note: there is no `IF` in SQL (there is in plpgsql). And: the EXISTS subquery is executed only once, even if uncorrelated (check the plan!) If the subquery *is* correlated, it will be part of the (JOIN) plan)

Comment: I know there is no `if` in SQL. I was saying that we are simulating an `if`. Is it a good idea to simulate an `if` like this?

Comment: *Simulating an if* like this is the only way to do it in pure SQL.

Comment: I meant: we could do it like this, or we could write a plpgsql function which could express a real `if`. Which method is preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even wrap the EXISTS() condition in a *pure* SQL function, and it will be executed only once:

---

```
-- \i tmp.sql

CREATE TABLE omg
        ( id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , must_pay integer NOT NULL
        );
INSERT INTO omg(id, must_pay) VALUES(1,0);

CREATE FUNCTION owe_money() RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$func$

SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1
        FROM omg o
        WHERE o.must_pay > 0
        );
$func$
-- language sql;
language sql STABLE;

EXPLAIN
SELECT owe_money();

INSERT INTO omg(id, must_pay) VALUES(2,100);

EXPLAIN
SELECT owe_money();

EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM omg
WHERE owe_money();
```

---

If you add the keyword `STABLE` to the function definition, the DBMS will know that the return value will **not** change (within the same transaction/statement). Without `STABLE`, the function will be invoked once for every row.

---

```
                                           QUERY PLAN                                            
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on omg  (cost=0.00..566.40 rows=713 width=8) (actual time=0.303..0.331 rows=2 loops=1)
   Filter: owe_money()
 Total runtime: 0.384 ms
(3 rows)
```

---

The result for the STABLE function is a one-time Filter:

---

```
                                             QUERY PLAN                                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.25..31.65 rows=2140 width=8) (actual time=0.304..0.316 rows=2 loops=1)
   One-Time Filter: owe_money()
   ->  Seq Scan on omg  (cost=0.25..31.65 rows=2140 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.009 rows=2 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 0.379 ms
```

(4 rows)

---

And the same condition as an uncorrelated subquery essentially yields the same plan as the STABLE function (now the subquery is executed once and its result (`$0`)is tested in the one-time Filter):

---

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM omg
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM omg o
        WHERE o.must_pay > 0
        );

                                                QUERY PLAN                                                
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.05..31.45 rows=2140 width=8) (actual time=0.022..0.034 rows=2 loops=1)
   One-Time Filter: $0
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Seq Scan on omg o  (cost=0.00..36.75 rows=713 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=1)
           Filter: (must_pay > 0)
           Rows Removed by Filter: 1
   ->  Seq Scan on omg  (cost=0.00..31.40 rows=2140 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.008 rows=2 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 0.081 ms
(8 rows)
```

---

But aren't we still scanning through the table and essentially doing where false **for each row** if that function returned false or where true if that function returned true?

---

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM omg
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM omg o
        WHERE o.id < 0
        );

                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=1.66..3.66 rows=100 width=8) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=0 loops=1)
   One-Time Filter: $0
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Index Only Scan using omg_pkey on omg o  (cost=0.14..1.66 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (id < 0)
           Heap Fetches: 0
   ->  Seq Scan on omg  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=8) (never executed)
 Total runtime: 0.063 ms
(8 rows)
```

---

*never executed* says it all.

Comment: When executing the last query (`SELECT * FROM omg WHERE owe_money()`) the planner gives: `"Seq Scan on omg  (cost=0.00..597.60 rows=753 width=8)" "  Filter: owe_money()"`. So doesn't that mean that it will be executed for each row?

Comment: The `stable` keyword, got it. The function is now executed once, hence the query is executed once. But aren't we still scanning through the table and essentially doing `where false` **for each row** if that function returned false or `where true` if that function returned true?

Comment: Thanks, very insightful!

Answer (score 2):

First, learn to use proper `join` syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1 JOIN
     t2
     ON t1.some_id = t2.some_id
WHERE not exists(select true from some_table where some_column = true);
```

The subquery should be executed only once.  However, ultimately that is up to the Postgres optimizer.  You can guarantee that the code is executed only once using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM t1 JOIN
     t2
     ON t1.some_id = t2.some_id LEFT JOIN
     some_table st
     ON st.some_column = true
WHERE st.some_column IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain why a `left join` enforces the planner to execute the query just once, while a `not exists` in the `where` clause is uncertain? (I knew already about the `join` syntax, thanks though. I was mainly focusing on that subquery.)

Comment: There is no difference, `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` and `NOT EXISTS(...)` both yield an anti-join plan. The only difference is that the `t2.*` columns become visible the outer query.

Comment: I am still not 100% following. What exactly did you mean with `The only difference is that the t2.* columns become visible the outer query.`?

Comment: @CarolineKwerts . . . That means that if you use `select *`, you'll get the columns from that table as well.

Comment: Thank you. Then, I am still confused why you said that with a `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL`, we have the guarantee that the query will only be executed once, but not with a simple `NOT EXISTS`. Why is that?

Comment: @CarolineKwerts . . . That is how `FROM` clauses work.  They need to be calculated first.  I suppose they *could* be evaluated multiple times, but it seems strange.  On the other hand, the `EXISTS` subquery *should* be calculated only once, but the optimizer could choose to evaluate it each time.

Comment: Got it! Thank you, again!